# get member value from object inside array in php

Tags: php, arrays, object

Can't seem to find the answer for this question: how to get a specific value (member value) from an array of objects?

My code is very simple:

```
$people = array();

class Person {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $family_name;
    public $dob;
    public $image;

    public function __construct($id, $name, $family_name, $dob, $image){
        $this->$id = (string) $id;
        $this->$name = (string) $name;
        $this->$family_name = (string) $family_name;
        $this->$dob = (string) $dob;
        $this->$image = (string) $image;
    }

    public function get_id(){
        return $this->id;
    }
}

for ($i=0;$i<$no_clients;$i++)
{
    array_push($people, new Person($_SESSION['user_clients'][$i]['client_id'], $_SESSION['user_clients'][$i]['client_name'], $_SESSION['user_clients'][$i]['client_family_name'], $_SESSION['user_clients'][$i]['client_dob'], ROOT_URL.$_SESSION['user_clients'][$i]['client_img']));
}
```

now I would like to get the id of one of the person from within the people array

```
$error = $people[$i]->get_id(); //doesn't seem to work
//not getting a value back even though the session variable is correct
```

as you've probably seen, I'm a PHP newbie so any advice would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Define "doesn't work"... Any errors? Also you should use `var_dump($people);` to see what the array contains.

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor is wrong (no $ sign in front of the properties)

```
   $people = array();

    class Person {
        public $id;
        public $name;
        public $family_name;
        public $dob;
        public $image;

        public function __construct($id, $name, $family_name, $dob, $image){
            $this->id = (string) $id;
            $this->name = (string) $name;
            $this->family_name = (string) $family_name;
            $this->dob = (string) $dob;
            $this->image = (string) $image;
        }

        public function get_id(){
            return $this->id;
        }
    }

    for ($i=0;$i<$no_clients;$i++)
    {
        $p=new Person($_SESSION['user_clients'][$i]['client_id'],       $_SESSION['user_clients'][$i]['client_name'], 
$_SESSION['user_clients'][$i]['client_family_name'], 
$_SESSION['user_clients'][$i]['client_dob'], 
ROOT_URL.$_SESSION['user_clients'][$i]['client_img']);
       //print_r($p); //--> check your object
        array_push($people, $p);
    }
```

//print_r($people);

```
Array ( [0] => Person Object ( [id] => 1 [name] => M [family_name] => C [dob] => 2011-07-21 [image] => image/1_margaret.jpg ) )
```

EDIT:

Reset that $i counter as probably it's last value was 1. Even better use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($people as $person){
    echo $person->get_id();
    }
```

Comment: Well spotted, thanks. The new problem has emerged now `Call to a member function get_id() on a non-object`. Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor code is not correct, you're incorrectly referencing your properties.  Remove the $ from the start of the property names.

Eg change

```
$this->$id = $id
```

to

```
$this->id = $id
```

Comment: Ah @radashk beat me to it ;-) Gets my +1.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out (newbie error). However, now I get `Call to a member function get_id() on a non-object`